# Returing to action method after global exception handler execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to globally catch any exception that is thrown in my models and controllers because I assume following logic in every action method:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(SomeViewModel someViewModel)
{
    try
    {
        // Do operation that may throw exception
    }
    catch (BLLException e)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", e.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.Info(e);
        RedirectToAction("ErrorPage", "ErrorControler");
    }

    return View(someViewModel);
}
```

A business logic layer will throw exceptions that user will be able to handle, and a message about that exception will be displayed to him. All other kinds of exception will be saved on server log and user will get an error page.

So since that logic will repeat in every controller I decided to move it to a global exception handler. But the question is: is it possible to go back from exception handler attribute to a line in action where it was thrown? I would like to achieve something like:

```
public class ExceptionGlobalHandler : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if( filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(BLLException))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", e.Message);
            //Continue executing where excetpion was thrown
        }
        catch (filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(BLLException))
        {
            _log.Info(e);
            RedirectToAction("ErrorPage", "ErrorControler");
        }
    }
}
```

Is it clear solution, and what is the best way of doing it?. What do you think about that kind of approach?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way in C# to do this, however you could build in some logic to do it for you.

In your Action's code, you'd just have to throw the exception later on, like record the exception internally and throw it only at the end of the method.  For example:

```
public void SomeAction()
{
    Exception innerEx;
    try
    {
        //some code that may/may not cause exceptions.
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        innerEx = e;
    }
    //some more execution code, equivelent to your "carry on at line x"
    throw innerEx;
}
```

Obviously this means your action's code would have to change, in addition to the wrapper you're using, but this, I think, is the unfortunate problem you have :(

TBH, I think you *should* rewrite the action's code, because a program that crashes should stop executing, and developers will generally put error checking code within their methods.

( to avoid confusion, I've been using Action to mean the System.Action class, NOT the mvc action class, because I know quite little about MVC, though I hope it makes sense anyway :P )

I would also say there may be something you've been missing - Have you considered seperating the methods you're calling into multiple separate calls?  Thus, you could call them all at once, reacting appropriately on an Exception result from one of the calls, while the others will carry on happily.